# A Beginner Trying to Use Else Statements C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm a student sitting a course in computing for the very first time and I've been trying to 'crack' this one for ages (I'm very new to this... sorry!). I can't seem to build a simple if/else statement in which if the conditions are met, it writes a positive response, and if not, a negative response. But I'm getting the errors:
Invalid expression term 'else'
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Sorry if this makes no sense, I'm very confused! :(

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you like bananas?");
    Console.ReadLine();
    if (Console.ReadLine() == "Yes") ;
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for your time!");
    }
    else;
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oh okay.");
    }
 }
}
```

}

Comment: remove the semicolon from else and from behind the if condition

Comment: The Rule of Semicolons is not "semicolon goes after everything", even though may appear to be the case at first.

Comment: You should probably review the online docs [if-else (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to remove the semicolon that you have after the else. 
generally its

```
if (condition) 
{
 //code
}
else 
{
 //code
}
```

and if you have more than one condition to meet you can have

```
if (condition)
{
 //code
}
else if (condition 2)
{
 //code
}
else 
{
 //code
}
```

the last else is used if none of the conditions are met above, its like a default behavior

Further, you don't need braces for only one line of code

```
if (condition) DoInterestingStuff();
else DoNotDoInterestingStuff();
```

A few example conditions(with unnessesary if-statements for clarification):

```
if (bananas == true)
if (bananas) // same as above
if (bananas != false) // not equal to false, thus true
if (totalBananas >= 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

No semi-colons:

```
 if (Console.ReadLine() == "Yes")
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for your time!");
 }
 else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Oh okay.");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

*Conditional Logic* though is simple, basic, it is incredibly important to learn correctly.  Your forgetting quite a bit of items:

- Incorrect placement of `;`.

You did:

```
if(Console.ReadLine() == "yes");
else;
```

The `;` at the end of that particular portion of the statement is invalid.  If your using Visual Studio or another IDE don't fight the tools, they try to help you with issues such as this.  For instance a squiggly line should appear under the `;` in that statement.

Your `if else` should be formatted in this manner:

```
if(value == "Yes")
{
     Console.WriteLine("Thank you...");
}

else if (value == "No")
{
     Console.WriteLine("No!");
}

else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Ah...");
}
```

You'll want to familiarize yourself with the `if else` and `switch` statement early on.  They're key piece in the foundation.  You can find some more detail on the [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx).  Really good examples an explination of the entire process.